# UITableView Edit Mode Add the cell defined by user?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to use the table editing mode so that the users can choose which Cells to add.

For eg I have

```
addArray = {@"Red",@"Blue",@"Green"};
```

Now , what I want is that when user enters the editing mode and presses the add button, he gets the options: `Red`,`Blue`,`Green` and selects the cell to be added.

```
-(IBAction)addButtonPressed
{
  [displayArray addObject:"User's Choice"];
  [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This tutorial link might help you http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/enabling-configuring-uitableview-edit-mode/

Comment: thnks....but i already went through it.
Didn't find what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `UIActionSheet` (see [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Select an option"
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

You will need to make your view controller conform to the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

Then, implement the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method in your view controller:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        // Red
        [displayArray addObject:"Red"];
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex + 1) {
        // Green
        [displayArray addObject:"Green"];
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex + 2) {
        // Blue
        [displayArray addObject:"Blue"];
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the easiest way to do it using UI controls provided by Apple (you could also use a `UIAlertView` but that's limited in the number of buttons you can add). Of course, you could always make a custom view controller to display the options, but that would be excessive if all you're doing is displaying a simple list of options.